# Dimension of matrix and some integrals

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

[image]

I know how to solve for 1 through 9. But could someone please explain how to get 10, 11, and 12?

Comment: BTW: the reason for the knot on 8 is that the knot is called the **figure-eight** knot.

Comment: Also, I think I'm missing something for $3$, since $\pi \neq 3$.

Comment: Yup, 8 is simply a knot that looks like 8, and 3, if you look carefully, there is a floor function. Thus, it is a floor of pi = 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to 10:** Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with a $1$ as its $i,j$ entry and zeros for every other entry.  It suffices to note that $\{A \in M^{5 \times 5}(\Bbb R) \mid A + A^T = 0\}$ has the basis
$\{E_{ij} - E_{ji} : 1 \leq i < j \leq 5\}$.

Comment: Could you check whether I am understanding correctly? To satisfy A+A^t = 0, it is either A = 0 or I-A^{t-1} = 0. The first case is trivial. The second case has the basis of two vectors, one containing 1 (and the other four are all zeros), and the other containing -1 in the different place. There are 10 possible options, thus its dimension is 10?

Comment: @JohnLee $t$ here denotes the transpose!!!

Comment: Oh my... that explains everything! I was wondering where that T comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for 11, use Green's theorem.

Comment: Thanks! I was having a trouble because I forgot the name of the theorem. I think I can use it for 11 and Residue theorem for 12.

Answer (score 0):

For 12, use Residue theorem. For each integral, the pole is around $z = n$ and is simple, so the residue is just $\frac{1}{\pi i}$ (the analytic part), so the each integral is $2$. There are six of them.